# Bitcoin tx with electrum has been unconfirmed for more than 24 hours and cannot be found on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, wallet, electrum

I tried to sell some BTC yesterday but the coins did not arrive and the tx remained unconfirmed and still is now. When I right click 'view on block explorer' it says 'Transaction not found'.

What can I do? I paid the recommended miner fee.

This is what it says when I click on view transaction:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have set a fee of 0.00000686 BTC (around 27 US cents) or 3 satoshi/vByte.

The average fee is currently about five times higher than your fee and you have three outputs. So the size in vBytes may be larger than average.

Various sites suggest 13 satoshi/vByte for a confirmation in an hour.

Since you have RBF enabled, maybe you should use that to set a higher fee.

Comment: Thank you, so that's probably the issue. What can I do now? Just wait for it to be confirmed? I've seen messages online of transactions taking weeks. Is there anything I can do to make it confirm faster?

Comment: You can use RBF to raise the fee. See [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/13866)